# object variable/ with block variable not set debug

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know what's wrong but whenever I run the macro, it is giving me a runtime error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set. A summary of this is that I want to copy only name (Sakinah), column A:Q from a read only workbook (master) and paste into Sakinah column A:Q. Right now, the copying part is working fine it's only the pasting part. This code is inputted into Sakinah and I have defined it as `Thisworkbook` I'm not sure what went wrong. Please help.

Below is my code: I have highlighted the part where the error occur:

```
Sub Update_ReadOnly_Click()

Dim copyStartCellSakinah As Long

Dim excelFilePath
Dim masterWorkBook As Workbook

Dim readLastCell As Long
Dim manager As String
Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
Dim d
Dim E
Dim F
Dim G
Dim H
Dim I
Dim J
Dim K
Dim L
Dim M
Dim N
Dim O
Dim P
Dim Q

Dim sheet As String


Dim sakinahWorkBookPath As String
Dim masterWorkBookPath As String
Dim Sakinahworkbook As ThisWorkbook

excelFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

masterWorkBookPath = excelFilePath & "\Master.xlsm"

Set masterWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(masterWorkBookPath, ReadOnly = True)

'get copy row
copyStartCellSakinah = 4

readLastCell = masterWorkBook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 

1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For x = 4 To readLastCell
    cell = "C" & x
    manager = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

        If UCase(manager) = "SAKINAH" Then
            sheet = "Sakinah"


            cell = "A" & x
            A = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "B" & x
            B = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "C" & x
            C = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "D" & x
            d = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "E" & x
            E = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "F" & x
            F = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "G" & x
            G = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "H" & x
            H = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "I" & x
            I = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "J" & x
            J = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "K" & x
            K = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "L" & x
            L = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "M" & x
            M = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "N" & x
            N = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "O" & x
            O = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "P" & x
            P = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
            cell = "Q" & x
            Q = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
```

'up until this point it's fine but when I get into Sakinahworkbook.worksheets(sheet) it is giving me an error.

```
 'copy


 cell = "A" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = A
         cell = "B" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = B
         cell = "C" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = C
         cell = "D" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = d
         cell = "E" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = E
         cell = "F" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = F
        cell = "G" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = G
        cell = "H" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = H
        cell = "I" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = I
        cell = "J" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = J
        cell = "K" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = K
        cell = "L" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = L
        cell = "M" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = M
        cell = "N" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = N
        cell = "O" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = O
        cell = "P" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = P
        cell = "Q" & copyStartCellSakinah
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cell).Value = Q


        copyStartCellSakinah = copyStartCellSakinah + 1

    End If
    Next x

' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    masterWorkBook.Close True             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set masterWorkBook = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True



'Me.Visible = True
MsgBox "Updated Successfully"
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be a little neater to investigate using a `range` rather than your code, so `range("a" & x & ":"q" & x).offset(`   a lot neater, and your a through to q's are not actually defined efficiently..  or even along these lines `ws2.range().value = ws1.range().value`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Help with making it a cleaner version? A complete novice here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this error you have to split declaration and assignment:

```
Dim Sakinahworkbook As ThisWorkbook
```

Into:

```
Dim Sakinahworkbook As Workbook
Set Sakinahworkbook = ThisWorkbook
```

Additionally I would recomend to simplify this code by doing copy operation in one loop instead of introducing variable for each column:

```
For x = 1 to  readLastCell
    For i = 1 to 17
        Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(x,i).Value = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(x,i).Value
    Next i
Next x
```

Comment: I have tried with the recommended solution to define the workbook as this workbook but it is still not working. As for the second line of code, would that run for my code? Can you help with the cleaner version? Really really a novice here. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure you have sheet "Sakinah" in your workbook?

Comment: yes, the sheet is named Sakinah in the Sakinah workbook.

Comment: there are two separate workbook. One masterworkbook and one Sakinahworkbook, so logically speaking it's supposed to be right. I honestly don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Try to change `Set Sakinahworkbook = ThisWorkbook` into `Set Sakinahworkbook = Workbooks("Sakinah.xlsm")` - of course it must be real name of Sakinah workbook. Maybe you have more workbooks. And additionally you will have to debug your code to find reason.

Comment: I have done the changes and it's giving me the same error. Would not defining it but changing `Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets(sheet)` to activeworkbook.worksheets("Sakinah")` gives me a subscript out of range issue. And I have more workbooks in the same file but all under different names. Would that effect it?

Comment: I think I solved it, instead of defining as Sakinahworkbook, I changed it all to Thisworkbook.worksheet. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Carmen `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` is identical to `Sakinahworkbook.Worksheets` if you have performed a `Set Sakinahworkbook = ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `Sakinahworkbook` as a `Workbook` and then `Set` it to `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Dim Sakinahworkbook As Workbook
Set Sakinahworkbook = ThisWorkbook
```

I'm very surprised that `As ThisWorkbook` is even allowed syntactically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it but it's still not working. Any suggestion?